# How to run Scala tests with the TestNG plugin in Scala IDE / Eclipse?

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, testng, scala-ide, typesafe-stack

I am using the [Typesafe Scala IDE](http://www.typesafe.com/stack/downloads/scala-ide) 3.0.0 together with the TestNG 6.8.1 plugin. What I really miss is the possibility to right-click on a Scala file, then select "Run As" and "TestNG Test" to launch the tests in the IDE. This feature works for Java-based TestNG tests, but not for tests written in Scala.

Silly example:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import org.testng.Assert

class MyTest {
  @Test
  def doSomeTesting() {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, false)
  }
}
```

I am also using Maven and the Surefire plugin, and the test is picked up and executed nicely when I run "mvn test". So I assume the Eclipse plugin does not recognize that the Scala file is a TestNG test. Is there a way to make the TestNG plugin work with Scala tests? Any working configuration could help.

Comment: It is not testng solution but specs2 allow you to set a junit test runner for a specifications. It allows to run spec from eclipse. http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Via+JUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem you described.
Instead of the *Run* menu, you should use the related shortcut.
That is to say **⌘ + ⌥ + X** then **N** for Mac users, **Ctrl + Alt + X** then **N** for the others.

Hope that  helps.

Comment: Re-Tested with Scala IDE 4.0.0 - context menu entry is still missing, but the shortcut works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Support for TestNG could (and should) be provided in a separate plug-in. I noticed there is already an [Eclipse plug-in for TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/), did you try to install it and see if it works?

Provided your Scala packages are in the right location (the package declaration matches the physical location of a source file), it should work fine.

Comment: I tried it again with TestNG plugin 6.8.6 and Scala IDE 3.0.1, but without success. Do you have a working setup? If so, it'd be interesting to see the differences.